# Django: сигнал post_save не срабатывает как ожидается

Tags: django

У меня есть основная модель пользователя User и две различных профиля пользователей  (Profile, Client) с полем OneToOneField к User. Для того, чтобы в зависимости от того какой тип пользователя выбирается при регистрации создавался соответствующий профиль я использую signals. Если в форме регистрации ставится галочка is_trainer, то должна создаваться модель Profile, если не ставиться - то модель Client. 
Сейчас получается, что в случае is_trainer = True все работает как надо и создается модель Profile, если же галочка не стоит то одновременно создаются две модели. Не могу понять почему так происходит.

**customuser**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(validators=[email_regex], unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(_('номер телефона'), validators=[phone_regex], max_length=13) 
    is_trainer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_client = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['phone']

    objects = UserManager()
```

**modelsProfile.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
```

**modelsClient.py**

```
class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='client')
```

**signals.py**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.is_trainer:
           profile = Profile.objects.create(user=instance)           

        else:
            profile = Client.objects.create(user=instance)
```

**SignUpView.py**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activate your blog account.'
            message = render_to_string('reg/acc_active_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(
                        mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/reg/success_signup/')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'reg/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):    
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=16, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Включает цифры и буквы латинского алфавита'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=16, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Повторите пароль'}))
    #is_trainer=forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':'control-input'}))
    is_trainer = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':'control-input'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('phone', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_trainer')
        widgets = {
            'email': EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Адрес электронной почты'}),
            'phone': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Номер телефона в формате +375293333333'}),


        }
```

Comment: "создаются две модели" какие 2 модели? покажите ещё и форму, может там что не так..

Comment: Модели Client и Profile ну и естественно User

Comment: вы уверены, что при создании объекта User при instance.is_trainer == False, у вас создаётся и Client и Profile. Перепроверьте. По предоставленному коду такого поведения не должно быть, возможно вы что-то не показали, из за чего такое поведение.

Comment: Блин, я затупил. Действительно создается user и client. Не знаю как это я так перепутал )  Часа три перелопачивал код. Спасибо)